# How to count duplicates with an If statement using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, macos, excel

I'm not amazing at creating macros, but I have some knowledge on creating some basic functions to help expedite some of the processes at my job. Currently I made a macros that copies a range of cells from one sheet to another sheet automatically. Please refer to the code below:

```
Sub Range_Copy()

Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("E2").Copy _

Destination:=Worksheets("Claim").Range("A5")

**Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("A2").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Claim").Range("B5")**

Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("H2").Copy _

Destination:=Worksheets("Claim").Range("D5")

Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("F2").Copy _

Destination:=Worksheets("Claim").Range("A7")

Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("G2").Copy _

Destination:=Worksheets("Claim").Range("C7")

**Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("C2").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Claim").Range("A9", "B9")**

**Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("J2").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Claim").Range("C9")**

Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("D2").Copy _

Destination:=Worksheets("Claim").Range("A11", "B11")

End Sub
```

The lines of code that are in bold, are the cells that contain either duplicates or are different. The cells in bold have a combination of letters, numbers and dates (mm/dd/yyyy). What I need help with regarding those bold lines of code is not to copy duplicates, but skip them, and if there are more than 3 cells that are different to print "See next tab". If they are different but less than three the macros continues to execute normally and to print them on one cell (preferably in this format: A, B, C). Hopefully some of this makes sense, and I do not mind clarifying anything that is needed. Thank you all for you help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: are you asking for help about `if...else... then..` you could try [MS Excel: How to use the IF-THEN-ELSE Statement (VBA)](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php)

Comment: I Downvoted/voted to close because it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Answer (score 0):

To copy cells only if they do not match you can use:

```
If Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("A2") <> Worksheets("Claim").Range("B5") then
    Worksheets("Additional Claims Detail").Range("A2").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Claim").Range("B5")
End if
```

And so on.

(I'm not sure I follow the rest of your question)